# Visual Studio: Is there a way to collapse all items of Solution Explorer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2022

I know that I can use Arrow Keys to collapse items of solution explorer one by one, but I would like to know if there is a way to collapse all items with only one operation. I want to know it because, today I have a solution with 6 projects that have at least **two hundred files** and if I try to collapse them one-by-one I will have a hard time.

[image: Tree View - Solution Explorer (Visual Studio)]

Comment: FYI, * is the expand-all key (This doesn't answer the question but is related.)

Comment: NOTE: built-in to VS 2012 and 2013 - read down for details

Comment: @Sprague \* only works with the dedicated key on the numeric keypad. How do you expand all, in the absence of a numeric keypad?

Comment: @Marco Lackovic (late reply) My best bet is to search  "expandall" in Tool>Option>Environment>Keyboard and set a hotkey.  (didn't test)

Answer (score 227):

It appears to be built in by default in Visual Studio 2013 onwards.

[image: Solution Explorer > Collapse]

Comment: Is there a hot key shortcut for this?

Comment: @RayLoveless no but you can set one in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

Comment: @AdamShort I found it convenient to assign action "Collapse All" to "Num /" key, it makes a good match for the "Num *" (Expand All)

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina How did you do that? `SolutionExplorer.CollapseAll`will only accept CTRL+something, trying to just use `\` does nothing for me

Comment: The CTRL key requirement only exists at global scope. Under the "Use new shortcut in:" set it to something more specific -- Solution Explorer would make the most sense.

Answer (score 24):

If you have ReSharper installed, you can right click on the solution in the solution explorer, and select "Collapse All".

Comment: Thanks Pete! I didn't know resharper did this either. Especially after hitting "*" by accident.

Comment: Request clarification or suggest improvement. Using resharper - what is the command / shortcut?

Answer (score 22):

You can use [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20101225034530/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands)

Right click on the project\solution on the solution explorer and choose Collapse Project:
[image]

Comment: love powercommands, except the "undo close" window that won't die.

Comment: I tryed to use it, but after it was installed on my machine, my vs2008 stopped to work. LOL

Comment: @Chris: I never tried it (I actually use the undo close window), but under Tools\Options\PowerCommands\Commands you can disable any feature you want.

Comment: PowerCommands tends to break the WPF designer, unfortunately.

Comment: Power Commands doesn't collapse solution folders either and instead expands them randomly

Answer (score 15):

Just use the ***number pad***'s Plus  <kbd>+</kbd>  and Minus  <kbd>-</kbd>  keys at the top-level node, to expand and collapse respectively  (Note:  <kbd>*</kbd>  also expands the whole list.)

For the toolbox, you need to use  <kbd>*</kbd>  and  <kbd>/</kbd>  instead for expand/collapse.  Go figure.

Comment: Unfortunately this only collapses/expands the current node (just like clicking on the expand/collapse icon), not any children, which I don't think is a solution for the OP: for instance if you have 3 projects, each with 2 folders, each with 10 folders. Collapsing the solution as a whole is great, but when you expand it again you're back to a list of 60 items rather than a list of 3 projects.

Comment: Num pad * expands all childrens (VS 2013)

Answer (score 14):

In VS 2019 just click Collapse All

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you have Resharper installed, there is an option called Collapse All and a shortcut key next to it.

[image: Solution Explorer > Resharper > Collapse]

Now this shortcut key will not work for you ! Unless you set it up using `Tools > Options > Keyboard`.

The command name is `ReSharper_CollapseInSolutionExplorer`.

Search using this command name and assign a shortcut key of your choice.

[image: Options > Keyboard > ReSharper_CollapseInSolutionExplorer]

and you now have a shortcut key ready to use to collapse all items in your solution explorer.

I know I am a little late to this discussion, but this surely gonna help some one or other.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is not default VS functionality (pre 2012), but, in this instance, the additional context menu item and shortcut is provided by Resharper.

Comment: In VS2015 with ReSharper 2016.1 this is now just `CollapseInSolutionExplorer`.

Answer (score 6):

Using Visual Studio 2017 and above

use shortcut

- Open  **Tools** > **Options** or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Under **Environment** tab > **Keyboard** 
  *(Also, you can create a shortcut for **Tools.CustomizeKeyboard** to open it directly*)

**To Collapse All**

- Search for "**SolutionExplorer.CollapseAll**"
- Add a new shortcut for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

  [image]

**To Expand All**

- Search for "**SolutionExplorer.Folder.CollapseAll**"
- Add a new shortcut for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

  [image]
- **Assign** >  **OK**

Comment: Is it really correct? SolutionExplorer.Folder.CollapseAll to expand all?

Answer (score 4):

There's a macro at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123213326/http://geekswithblogs.net/scottkuhl/archive/2007/04/09/111195.aspx) for Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do I run that macro into VS2008?

Comment: go to Tools -> Macros -> Macro IDE, and paste the macro code in a module

Answer (score 4):

The VisualStudio extension [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) provides collapsing.

[Download](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496/) from VisualStudioGallery.

The current version only supports VS2010 or higher, but you can install older versions side-by-side.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2012 is out on 8/15/2012, so I suggest upgrading to that to get a fast "Collapse All" toolbar button previously available only in the Productivity Power Tools' Solution Navigator, which was sometimes too slow to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

take a look on this
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7272073b-32d4-4a84-93f7-77d09fb16f01

Answer (score 0):

It’s very simple now in visual studio 2022 17.7 version. It’s easier and more flexible.

When you right-click on a node in Solution Explorer. You can use this to collapse the selected node as well as its descendent nodes. We've also mapped this as a shortcut via the Ctrl+Left arrow keys.

[image: from one YouTube channel]

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#collapse-all-descendants-for-solution-explorer

Answer (score -1):

Use the Visual Studio extension that fits your version of Visual Studio.
In my case (I use Visual Studio 2012) I use the extension [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2012), but, unfortunately this exist only for VS 2010 and latter... For VS 2008 there is a similar extension: [Power Commands](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221082213/http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com:80/PowerCommands).

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Go to Tools => Extensions in Visual Studio and Install the specified add-ins to have the desired functionnality.

Answer (score -4):

Delete the `*.suo` and `*.csproj.user` files, and reopen the solution/projects.

Comment: What preferences? The projects will still compile the same.

Comment: It will compile, but you will loose currently opened tabs, startup projects (painful if you have multiple), as well as other per-user settings.